# C++ call delete does not free memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

I want to test what delete in c++ can do so wrote the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
  A(string s):a(s){}
  string getS(){
    return a;
  }
private:
  string a;
};

class B{
public:
  B(string str):s(str){}
  void setV(A a){
    v.push_back(a);
  }
  string getS(){
    return s;
  }
private:
  vector<A> v;
  string s;
};

int main(){
  A a("abc");
  B* b = new B("cba");
  b->setV(a);
  cout<<b->getS()<<endl;
  cout<<a.getS()<<endl;
  delete b;
  cout<<b->getS()<<endl;
  cout<<a.getS()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And I still got the following output:

```
cba
abc
cba 
abc
```

looks like I can still get access the memory for both a and b?
So my question would be
1.Why do I have access to b, since I have called delete on it?
2.Why do I have access to a, since b's destructor is called so the memory of vector containing a should be free?

Cheers

Comment: Duplicate question. You're invoking "Undefined behavior" by accessing deleted memory.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  You're not physically removing the bytes from your computer - you're just relinquishing ownership.

Answer (score 2):

The free function does not clear or zero out memory. It only makes it a free block that is ready to be malloc'ed by the memory manager.

The pointers and structures all hold the same values, and when referenced will create undefined behavior. Either throwing an exception/error or retrieving the information inside.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Why do I have access to b, since I have called delete on it?

It is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything is possible. It may work, may not, may get an error, a segment fault, may crash, and so on.

> 2.Why do I have access to a, since b's destructor is called so the memory of vector containing a should be free?

`a` was copied when you call `b->setV(a);`, so the `vector` in `b` has nothing to do with `a`.